# Why use object files in C?

Tags: c, linker, include

When I compile a C program, for ease I've been including the source file for a certain header at the end. So, if main.c includes util.h, util.h will have all the headers util.c will use, outlines types or structs, etc, then at the very end it include util.c. Then, when I compile I only have to use gcc main.c -o main, and the rest is all taken care of.

I've been looking up C coding standards, trying to figure out what the best way to do things is, and there are just so many, and so many conflicting opinions I don't know what to think. Why do so many places reccomend compiling object files individually instead of including all of them in a web? util never touches anything but util.c, so the two are perfectly independent, and in theory (my theory) it would be fine, but I'm probably wrong since this is computer science and people are wrong even when they're right, so if I'm already wrong I'm probably wrong.

Some people say header files should ONLY be prototypes, and the source file be the one that includes it, and it's necessary system headers. From purely as aesthetic point of view I much prefer having all the info (types, system headers used, prototypes) in the header (in this case util.h) and having ONLY function code in util.c (excluding one "#include "util.h"" at the very top).

I guess the point I'm getting at is, with all this stuff that works, selecting a method sounds arbitrary to someone who doesn't understand the background (me). Please tell me why and what.

Comment: Q: Why use object files in C?  A: So you don't have to incur the time and expense of recompiling every line of code in the entire project if you don't have to :)

Comment: That's really it? So if compile time doesn't bother me at all, there's no reason to bother doing anything different than what I'm doing? For small projects like my own, manually compiling all the files would be more a time consumer.

Comment: @DakotaWest the second reason is modular programming.

Comment: @DakotaWest, even if your project is a single source file with less than 10 lines of code, writing a makefile is the best timesaver you can make.  Manual compilation (ie, invoking the compiler directly) is hardly ever worth it.

Comment: @Dakota Find out what a Makefile is and use one.

Comment: I'm looking at makefiles, but according to 2.4 on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction) page, the seperate object files still include each other. So wouldn't every object that uses buffer.h need to be rebuilt if buffer were changed?

Comment: @Dakota Only if you change one of its dependencies (e.g. a header file). If you just change to body of the module (the `.c`-file) anything should work fine without recompilation. This is because the compiler only needs the header files to figure out enough to write code against another module.

Comment: @Dakota On another notice, taking the GNU manual as a tutorial on what a Makefile is is like trying to understand arithmetic by looking at the axioms without any explanation at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While your program is small, this will work. At some point, however, your program will get large enough that recompiling the whole program every time you change one line is a pain in the rear.

This -- even more than avoiding editing huge files -- is the reason to split up your program. If main.c and util.c are seperately compiled into object files, changing one line in a function in main.c will no longer require you to recompile all the code in util.c.

By the time your program is made up of a few dozen files, this will be a *big* win.

Comment: In addition, breaking up files means that once they have been tested, you don't need to retest them.  If I have all the lines in one file, I can't justify which functions don't need to be rebuilt and tested.

Comment: Agreed -- as things stand now, all the things which have to happen when a file changes (compile, test, commit, etc) are happening for the *whole* program any time *any* part changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that you want to include only what is needed for that file to be independent. This reduces overall compilation times by allowing the compiler to only read the headers that are necessary rather repeatedly reading every header when it might not need to. For example, if your `util.c` method utilises functions and/or types in `<stdio.h>` but your `util.h` doesn't, then you would want to include `<stdio.h>` only in `util.c` so that when the compiler compiles `util.c` it only *then* includes `<stdio.h>`, but if you include `<stdio.h>` in your `util.h`  instead, then every source file that includes `util.h` is also including `<stdio.h>` whether it needs it or not.

This is very negligible for small projects with only a handful of files, but proper header inclusion can affect compilation times for larger projects.

With regards to the question about "object files": when you compile a source file into an object file, you create a shortcut that allows a build system to only recompile the source files that have outdated object files. This is an effective way to significantly reduce compilation times especially for large projects.

Comment: This isn't *quite* right. Since header files are (or should be) protected from multiple inclusion with #ifdefs, his approach will only parse studio.h once, while multiple files will parse it once per file. But what he wins this way, he loses by recompiling the entirety of *his* code every time. :-)

Comment: @jimwise: I think you misunderstood what I meant. If each translation unit that included `util.h` also included `stdio.h` it would increase compilation times whether that translation unit needed `stdio.h` or not. If `stdio.h` is only found in `util.c` then any translation units that don't need `stdio.h` no longer include it, hence decreasing compilation times.

Comment: He's parsing stdio.h once now.  After splitting, he'll be parsing it *at least* once. Right?

Answer (score 1):

First, including a .c file from a .h file is completely bass-ackwards.

The "standard" way of doing it follows a line of thought roughly like this:

You have a library, containing dozens of functions. Keeping everything in one big source file means that anyone using your library would have to link the *whole* library, even if he uses only a single function of it. (Imagine linking the whole C standard library for a `puts( "Hello" )`.)

So you split things across multiple source files, which are compiled individually. Whenever you make changes to one of your functions, you have to re-translate only one small source file and update the library archive (or executable) - instead of re-translating the whole thing every time. (This is *still* an issue, because code sizes have somewhat kept up with CPU improvements. Compiling something like the Boost lib can still take several minutes on not-too-fancy hardware...)

Now you are in a pinch, however. The function is defined inside the .c file, and the corresponding .o file can conveniently be linked (via a .a archive if need be). *However*, to actually *address* the function (provided by the .o file) properly from another source file (a.k.a. "translation unit"), your compiler needs to know the function name, its parameter list, and its return type. This is why the *declaration* of the function (i.e., the function head without its body) is put in a separate header (.h) file.

Other source files can now `#include` the header file, address the function properly (without the compiler being aware of what the function actually *does*), and when all parts of your library / program are compiled into .o files, *then* everything is linked together.

The source file includes its own header basically to make sure the two files agree on the function declaration. ;-)

That's about it, as far as I can be bothered to write it up right now. Putting everything into one monolithic source file is *barely* acceptable (actually, no, it isn't, not for anything beyond about 200 lines), but including the .c file at the end of the .h file either means you learned your C coding by looking at god-awful code instead of a good book, or whoever tutored you should never tutor another person on C coding in his life. No offense intended. ;-)

**PS:** Header files also provide a good summary / oversight of a piece of code. Languages that don't provide headers - Java, for example - need IDE's or documentation tools to extract this kind of information. Personally, I found header files to be a benefit, not a liability.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `*.h` and `*.c` files as customary: `*.h` files are `#include`d in `*.c` files; `*.h` contain *only* macro definitions, data type declarations, function declarations, and `extern` data declarations. *All* definitions are in `*.c` files. That is how everybody else organizes C programs, do your fellow humans (who some day might need to understand your program) a favor. If something in `file.c` is used outside, you'd write `file.h` containing the declarations of whatever in that file is to be used outside, and include that in `file.c` (to check that declarations and definitions agree) and in all using `*.c` files. If a bunch of `*.h` are *always* included together, it might mean that the splitup into `*.c` isn't right (or at least that of the `*.h`; perhaps you should make one `.h` including all those declarations, and creating `*.h` for internal use where needed among the group of related `*.c` files).

[If a program written as you outline crosses my path, I can assure you I'll avoid it like the plague. The extra obfuscation might be wellcome in [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/), but not by me. It is a sure sign of somebody who doesn't know how to organize a program cleanly, and so the program probably isn't worth trying it out.]

**Re: Separate compilation:** You break up a C program so the pieces are easier to understand, you can hide details of how things work in the C files (think `static`), this provides support for Parnas' modularity. It also means that if you change a file, you don't have to recompile everything.

**Re: Differing C programming standards:** Yes, there are lots of them around. Pick one you feel confortable with, and stick to that. If you work on a project, adhere to their standards.

Answer (score 0):

The "include in a single translation unit" approach becomes very inefficient for any significantly sized project, it is impractical for projects that are distributed amongst multiple developers.

Morover when creating static libraries, if everything in the library were from a single translation unit, any code linked to it would get all the library code regardless of whether it is referenced or not.

A project using a build manager such as *make* or the features available in most IDEs uses header file dependencies to allow an *incremental build*; only compiling those sources that are modified or dependent on modified files.  The dependencies are determined by the file inclusions, so minimising redundant dependencies speeds build time.

A typical commercial project can comprise hundreds of thousands of lines of code and a few hundred source files; full rebuild times can vary from minutes to hours.  If in your development cycle you have to wait that long between code changes and test, productivity would be very low!